# LiteDB query in 2 related Collections

Tags: c#, relationship, bson, dbref, litedb

I have a `LiteDB` database with **2 POCO classes**

- Author that includes "`Id`" and "`Name`", as Properties
- Book  that includes "`Title`" "`Id`" and "`Author`"(this property has a
  `bson` reference to the Author's collection)

I'm trying to query the book collection in order to retrieve all authors named "`John`" that wrote one or more books.

```
 class Author // collection "authors"
 {
     [BsonId]
     public int id {get; set;}
     public string Name{get; set;}
 }
 class Book //collection "books"
 {
     [BsonId]
     public int id {get; set;}
     public string Title{get; set;}
     [BsonRef("authors")] 
     public Author author {get; set;}
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Same problem was solved here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675677/how-to-join-in-litedb